# Qual é a deferença entre `UNDEFINED` e `IS NOT DEFINED`

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma irritante confusão entre as mensagens de erros `undefined // (indefinido)` e `ReferenceError: x is not defined (Erro de Referência: x não está definido)`.

Mensagens de erros do Chrome.

```
var a;

a; // undefined (indefinido)
b; // ReferenceError: b is not defined (Erro de Referência: b não está definido)

typeof a; // "undefined" ("indefinido")

typeof b; // "undefined" ("indefinido")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A diferença é que `undefined` refere-se ao valor da variável e `is not defined` é uma mensagem de erro que indica que a variável não existe no programa que está a correr.

#### `a; // undefined (indefinido)`

A variável está declarada no script, mas não tem valor atribuído. Não foi setado um valor, por isso é indefenido o seu valor.

Repara que isso pode acontecer de maneiras diferentes:

```
var a;
console.log(a); // undefined
```

mas também:

```
console.log(a); // undefined
var a;
```

e este último caso não é igual ao problema de `b` pois algures no script a variável é declarada. Isto já não é possível (e ainda bem) com `let` ou `const`, aí daria um erro:

> Cannot access 'a' before initialization

#### `b; // ReferenceError: b is not defined`

Na verdade hoje em JavaScript moderno (caso não existisse `var`) seria mais correto o erro dizer `is not declared` ou `is not initialised` pois ela pode estar declarada mas não ter valor atribuído.

Neste caso a variável `b` nunca é declarada por isso não pode ser usada. Mesmo que tivesses na linha de baixo `b = 'foo';` isso não é o mesmo que `var b = 'foo';` e por isso a variável nunca é inicializada.

#### `typeof a|b`

O caso do `typeof` é diferente pois uma das características do `typeof` é poder sondar o valor de do operando mesmo que ele não esteja declarado/inicializado.

Answer (score 1):

`undefined` é um tipo de valor para representar vazio, similar ao `null`. Por que JavaScript tem dois tipos de vazio causa discussões, mas a ideia é que `undefined` seja usado como valor padrão de uma variável não inicializada, enquanto `null` é utilizado em variáveis que o programador definiu manualmente como vazias.

`Not definied` é uma exceção lançada quando você tenta acessar uma variável que não foi declarada. É uma definição simples, mas um comportamento estranho, pois `b` deveria ser o equivalente de `window.b`, e enquanto a propriedade `window.b` pode ser acessada (possuindo o valor `undefined`), `b` só poderá ser acessado depois de ser declarado ou inicializado.

O que o macro `typeof` faz é basicamente tratar a exceção. `window.b !== undefined`, `typeof b !== 'undefined'`, `'b' in window` são todas formas válidas de verificar se `b` existe sem lançar uma exceção.

Comment: Vou discordar um pouco de vc :D... "vazio" é um valor definido. Logo, "undefined" é algo que não foi definido, logo não tem valor nenhum, nem mesmo "vazio".

Comment: Só complementando, isso seria vazio `var a = '';` e isso seria "undefined": `var a;`. Logo, vazio não tem nada a ver com undefined.

Comment: Diferença entre "vazio" e `null`/`undefined`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9vg8.jpg